# Is there a safe way to delete unused partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I had several copies of Windowses installed on my HDD. I have also dual booted the current copy of windows with Ubuntu. It seems, that there are many unused 200-500MB partitions left that I want to get rid of. The problem is, I don't know which partitions can be safely deleted. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here is the screenshot of partition manager:

[image]

Comment: None of those partitions are MBR partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound Why not? They are used by system. Are they all safe to delete? And where are the MBR partitions then?

Comment: MBR is not partition at all. It is bootcode plus patition _table_

Comment: I see, edited the question.

Comment: Delete and do what with the space?  If it's empty space, you can do whatever you want with it; repartition it, change the filesystems, etc.  However, if Ubuntu is installed, it looks like Windows isn't recognizing what's there.  What does this look like using a Linux partition manager?

Comment: @user1700494 While you are right that the MBR is bootcode plus a table (plus space for the "magic signature"), the question in Axelander Lomia's earlier comment does reflect some current common usage.  Partitions specified by the MBR's partition table are often called "MBR partitions", to distinguish from other types of partitions that may be specified in other ways (like a BSD disklabel, or GPT...  maybe LVM).

Comment: @AlexanderLomia - You have more then 4 partitions which points to GPT style partitions instead of MBR style.  *The row isn't expanded but it appears you have an EFI partition.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed Ubuntu on that system it is very much possible the partitions listed are still in use by Ubuntu.

I suggest you boot into Ubuntu and take a look at the partition table from there, and also look at the fstab (/etc/fstab) or the output of 'mount' to see which partitions are used from Ubuntu.

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

will list your partitions (on Disk 0), and

$ mount | grep '/dev/sd[a-z]'

will show currently mounted filesystems (except swap and assuming no LVM is in use).

I also often use

$ sudo blkid

to get a quick overview of block devices and their uses/filesystems.

In the end only you will be able to know which partitions you use.

I strongly suggest to always have a backup when fiddling with partitions, and don't delete partitions that are at the beginning of your drive (e.g first two on your Disk 0) because that may cause boot failures.

Comment: I concur, although if the partition table is GPT, as others have speculated, `fdisk` may not be useful, depending on the `fdisk` version. Instead, I recommend using `parted` (as in `sudo parted /dev/sda print`) or the GUI GParted. These tools work with both MBR and GPT disks. GParted also shows where partitions are currently mounted.